# command line in java

Tags: java

I hava code that process files by threads , my question is how can I enter file name to process it ?

what is arugment command line and how do we deal with it ?
 enter code here

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;

public class DigestThread extends Thread {
    private File input;

    public DigestThread(File input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input);
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            DigestInputStream din = new DigestInputStream(in, sha);
            int b;
            while ((b = din.read()) != -1)
                ;
            din.close();
            byte[] digest = sha.digest();
            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(input.toString());
            result.append(": ");
            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
                result.append(digest[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            File f = new File(args[i]);
            Thread t = new DigestThread(f);
            t.start();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: A filename is just a string.

Comment: I'm confused - what doesn't work about your code? What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you ever start your program from the command line?

Comment: I know that , but how do we enter that string into program ? thanks for sharing

Comment: No , I did not start it in command line but in NetBeans

Comment: if I start program in NetBanes , the program does not request any input and terminate so how do we enter file name to process it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void setFile(File f){
input = f;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
setFile(fc.getSelectedFile());
Thread t = new DigestThread(f);
t.start( );
}
}
```

Comment: there is no any wrong in the code , but the problem is the dealing with arugment command line . if I start program in NetBanes , the program does not request any input and terminate so how do we enter file name to process it ?

Answer (score 0):

In Command Line:

**java DigestThread filename1 filename2**

In NetBeans:

go to Project: **Properties** --> **Run** --> and type the arguments next to "**Arguments**"

**Run** | **Run Main Project**

Answer (score 0):

You can send the name of the file as a command line  argument to your Java program.

For example,

in CMD.EXE: assuming `java.exe` is in the environment path variable `PATH`

`X:\Path\to\your\dotClass\File> java DigestThread path/to/your/filename.ext`

or in BASH: assuming `java` is in the environment path variable `PATH`

`/path/to/your/dotClass/file $ java DigestThread path/to/your/filename.ext`

Also, if you're using Netbeans, see here http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html on how to start the program with a command line argument.